# LogicApps runs history - how to hide or remove from admin

Tags: azure, logic, history

I have a LogicApp that takes a file from sftp and content of file sends using https post service. File content is send as body, url is prepared in HTTP logicApp block. This is working good, works fine. When I check runs history I can see HTTP post call URL and Body also - this is ok for me as an owner of LogicApp but there are several other people that are owners (resource group). Is there any way to hide runs history from other users than specified? This should not be visible even for LogicApp resource group admin, should be only visible for specific person. If this is not posible is there any way to remove runs history?

Best Regards,
Wito

Answer (score 0):

So far there's no way we can administer these run history from Logic Apps.